# Poco HTML Form POST data coming through empty

Tags: php, c++, apache, poco-libraries

I have a desktop application passing POST data (text and an image file) onto a PHP file on an Apache Webserver. For some reason the POST data is coming through empty. Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this?

All I am trying for now is to display the POST data using:

```
<?php print_r($_POST); ?>
```

But I'm getting nothing. No errors and no data. The strange thing is this works perfectly on my old server - but with my new host the $_POST var is coming through empty so I'm confident it isn't an issue with the app.

The desktop app was built by someone else using Poco to send the HTML Form data so I don't know too much about it but I know if definitely works as it is currently working on my current other webserver.

Weirder still, when I don't attach an image everything works as expected. As soon as an image is attached (<100kb) I get no data whatsoever.

The Poco HTML Form is using `multipart/form-data` as the encoding type when an file is attached and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` when there is no attachment (default).

I'm stumped here and wondering if anyone knows what could be going on or at least what I should be looking to try at?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I also forgot to mention that it works if I submit it from another webpage without issue.

Double edit: Here is the equivalent of the form in HTML:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="http://DOMAIN.COM/savedata.php" method="POST">
    name: <input type="text" name="name" /><br />
    email: <input type="text" name="email" /><br />
    gender: <select name="gender"><option value="0">Female</option><option value="1">Male</option></select><br />
    photo: <input name="photo" type="file" /><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" /></form>
```

Comment: "As soon as an image is attached (<100kb) I get no data whatsoever" That sounds like a file size limit to me. Did you look into that yet?

Comment: Thanks Paul. I thought that at first but 100kb is a very small size. Also `post_max_size` is set to 8M so I don't think that is the issue. 

I also forgot to mention that it works it I submit it from another webpage without issue.

Comment: Can you add the HTML source code of your form to your question?

Comment: Hi Jocelyn, its not a HTML form its actually using Poco and C++ to build and send it. That said though there is nothing complicated about the form itself, a couple of text fields and one file attachment. I'll add a html equivalent to the question anyways.